# NextJs builds serverless app with static HTML files instead of lambdas

Tags: next.js, aws-serverless

I am trying to build an application with next serverless, but instead of outputting JS files in the expected folder (`next/serverless/pages/`), my pages become static HTML files, nextjs even says so when building;

```sh
Compiled successfully. 

Page            Size     Files  Packages                                                                                
┌   /_app       2.04 kB    195         0                                                                                
├   /_document                                                                                                          
├   /_error     7.58 kB    230         0                                                                                
├ ⚡ /About      420 B      196         0                                                                                
└ ⚡ /Index      420 B      196         0                                                                                                                                                                                                        
λ  (Lambda)       page was emitted as a lambda (i.e. getInitialProps)                                                   
⚡  (Static File)  page was prerendered as static HTML
```

This is my `next.config.js`:

```js
module.exports = {
  target: "serverless",
  distDir: "../../dist/functions/next"
};
```

The output of the build with two pages (`About` and `Index`) is:

```
dist/functions/next/serverless/pages/
  _error.js
  404.html
  About.html
  Index.html
```

I need them to be JS files because I require them as modules later for HTTP requests through firebase functions

Comment: everything looks fine. Can you include your `index.js`? Also, which version of `next.js` are you using? are you using `next build` for building?

Answer (score 4):

Starting from Next.js 9 it uses [Automatic Static Optimization](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#automatic-prerendering) by default when you are doing a static export.

Static HTML `.html` is good for performance, however, for some reason if you wish to export certain files as `.js` Next.js 9 also supports that [partial static export](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9#automatic-partial-static-export).

Just include `getInitialProps` in the pages that you wish to export as `.js` then it will output the javascript file instead of the HTML file.

```
class Index extends Component {

  // just have to add this line into any of your `pages/any-file.js`
  static getInitialProps(ctx) {
    return {};
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Index Page</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Index;
```